# A Google Apps Script that was working fine on 9/13 is not working today, and I haven't changed it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, typeerror, google-forms

I'm a newbie working at building automation scripts for my partner's therapy practice. I made a script to populate a patient information form, with the info coming from a Google Form to a Google Sheet; the script is triggered on form submit.

Expected behavior: the form is submitted, goes to the Google Sheet where the script is attached, and the script populates a template and saves it as a Google Doc copy. This worked until 9/13, and the completed report is saved on my Google Drive. This worked until 9/13, and the completed report is saved on my Google Drive. Between two days ago and today I have changed nothing.

Today on submitting the form, first got "An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later." I closed the browser (Safari), reopened all the relevant files, and clicked Run. Got the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'values') PatientResponsesFormReport    @ Code.gs:2"

Here's the code. I think the error report refers to the e.values reference in line 2: (I did a cut and paste from the Editor into a Code Block, but the syntax highlighting isn't showing. Guess I'm really showing myself as a newbie.)

```
function PatientResponsesFormReport(e) {
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var email = e.values[2];
  var firstName = e.values[3];
  var lastName = e.values[4];
  var birthdate = e.values[5];
  var contactMethod = e.values[6];
  var safetyConcerns = e.values[7];
  var textNumber = e.values[8];
  var phoneNumber = e.values[9];
  var mailingAddress = e.values[10];
  var physicalAddress = e.values[11];
  var insuranceMemberID = e.values[12];
  var gender = e.values[13];
  var pronouns = e.values[14];
  var relationshipStatus = e.values[15];
  var insuranceGroupID = e.values[16];
  var mood = e.values[17];
  var affect = e.values[18];
  var orientation = e.values[19];
  var functioning = e.values[20];
  var suicideThoughts = e.values[21];
  var suicideComments = e.values[22];
  var presentsContinues = e.values[23];
  var currentSymptoms = e.values[24];
  var pastSymptoms = e.values[25];
  var relativesSymptoms = e.values[26];
  var referralSource = e.values[27];
  var emergencyContactName = e.values[28];
  var eduBackground = e.values[29];
  var emergencyContactNumber = e.values[30];
  var employment = e.values[31];
  var presentingConcern = e.values[32];
  var concernHistory = e.values[33];
  var symptomTrigger = e.values[34];
  var symptomSelfImpact = e.values[35];
  var symptomRelationshipImpact = e.values[36];
  var symptomCoping = e.values[37];
  var medConditions = e.values[38];
  var doctorCare = e.values[39];
  var medications = e.values[40];
  var fooChildhood = e.values[41];
  var fooCurrent = e.values[42];
  var socialInfo = e.values[43];
  var currentRels = e.values[44];
  var resources = e.values[45];
  var eduConcerns = e.values[46];
  var legalConcerns = e.values[47];
  var cultureConcerns = e.values[48];
  var religConcerns = e.values[49];
  var suicideUrges = e.values[50];
  var suicidePlans = e.values[51];
  var suicideAttempts = e.values[52];
  var insCarrier = e.values[53];
  var issues2 = e.values[54];


  //file is the template file, and you get it by ID
  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById('1zsvcI6JwY_kdSCVs7w6gSh_VmwwtIe1E_Fm28b0GyvM'); 
  
  
  //We can make a copy of the template, name it, and optionally tell it what folder to live in
  //file.makeCopy will return a Google Drive file object
  var templateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1j619jPkXGATxs99Uh6BbDu4e4lV0za_3');
  var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(lastName + ', ' + firstName,templateResponseFolder);
  
  
  //Once we've got the new file created, we need to open it as a document by using its ID
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId()); 
  
  //Since everything we need to change is in the body, we need to get that
  var body = doc.getBody(); 
  
  var header = doc.getHeader();
  
  //Then we call all of our replaceText methods
  body.replaceText('{{lastName}}', lastName); 
  body.replaceText('{{firstName}}', firstName);  
  body.replaceText('{{email}}', email);
  body.replaceText('{{birthdate}}', birthdate); 
  body.replaceText('{{timestamp}}', timestamp);
  body.replaceText('{{contactMethod}}', contactMethod);
  body.replaceText('{{contactSafetyCheck}}', safetyConcerns);
  body.replaceText('{{phoneNumber}}', phoneNumber);
  body.replaceText('{{textNumber}}', textNumber); 
  body.replaceText('{{physAddress}}', physicalAddress);
  body.replaceText('{{mailAddress}}', mailingAddress);
  body.replaceText('{{emergContactName}}', emergencyContactName);
  body.replaceText('{{emergContactNumber}}', emergencyContactNumber);
  body.replaceText('{{referralSource}}', referralSource);
  body.replaceText('{{eduBackground}}', eduBackground);
  body.replaceText('{{employment}}', employment);
  body.replaceText('{{gender}}', gender);
  body.replaceText('{{pronouns}}', pronouns);
  body.replaceText('{{relStatus}}', relationshipStatus);
  body.replaceText('{{insCarrier}}', insCarrier);
  body.replaceText('{{insMemberID}}', insuranceMemberID);
  body.replaceText('{{insGroupID}}', insuranceGroupID);
  body.replaceText('{{presentingConcern}}', presentingConcern);
  body.replaceText('{{concernHistory}}', concernHistory);
  body.replaceText('{{currentSymptoms}}', currentSymptoms);
  body.replaceText('{{pastSymptoms}}', pastSymptoms);
  body.replaceText('{{famSymptoms}}', relativesSymptoms);
  body.replaceText('{{symptomTrigger}}', symptomTrigger);
  body.replaceText('{{symptomSelfImpact}}', symptomSelfImpact);
  body.replaceText('{{symptomRelImpact}}', symptomRelationshipImpact);
  body.replaceText('{{symptomCoping}}', symptomCoping);
  body.replaceText('{{medConditions}}', medConditions);
  body.replaceText('{{doctorCare}}', doctorCare);
  body.replaceText('{{medications}}', medications);
  body.replaceText('{{curentRels}}', currentRels);
  body.replaceText('{{fooChildhood}}', fooChildhood);
  body.replaceText('{{fooCurrent}}', fooCurrent);
  body.replaceText('{{socialInfo}}', socialInfo);
  body.replaceText('{{resources}}', resources);
  body.replaceText('{{eduConcerns}}', eduConcerns);
  body.replaceText('{{legalConcerns}}', legalConcerns);
  body.replaceText('{{cultureConcerns}}', cultureConcerns);
  body.replaceText('{{religConcerns}}', religConcerns);
  body.replaceText('{{suicideThoughts}}', suicideThoughts);
  body.replaceText('{{suicideComments}}', suicideComments);
  body.replaceText('{{suicideUrges}}', suicideUrges);
  body.replaceText('{{suicidePlans}}', suicidePlans);
  body.replaceText('{{suicideAttempts}}', suicideAttempts);



  header.replaceText('{{lastName}}', lastName);
  header.replaceText('{{firstName}}', firstName);


  //Lastly we save and close the document to persist our changes
  doc.saveAndClose(); 
}
```

Any counsel on how to get this and the other scripts on this format working again would be greatly appreciated. I confess I'm stymied.

Comment: Sounds like your run did not have any object passed at all, but was expecting an object with a property [values] containing an array. Might the original error been a one-off and the error in your testing be from calling the script without proper arguments?

Comment: Normally I would have thought that someone ran the script from the script editor because it returns the exact same error because there is no event object

Comment: Thanks for the information, guys. I did run the script from the script editor, which is where I got the error message that I reported. However, when I ran the script by submitting the associated form, the form went right to the Google Sheet as predicted, but produced no document, which had happened without problems two days ago. I'm all but certain I did nothing to the script in the meantime, and yet the problem seems to be with the script syntax. So stupid newbie question: what object should there be, and why might it have worked two days ago?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63851123/

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Consider adding a answer explaining how the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function PatientResponsesFormReport(e) {
  try {
    var timestamp = e.values[0];
    var email = e.values[2];
    var firstName = e.values[3];
    var lastName = e.values[4];
    var birthdate = e.values[5];
    var contactMethod = e.values[6];
    var safetyConcerns = e.values[7];
    var textNumber = e.values[8];
    var phoneNumber = e.values[9];
    var mailingAddress = e.values[10];
    var physicalAddress = e.values[11];
    var insuranceMemberID = e.values[12];
    var gender = e.values[13];
    var pronouns = e.values[14];
    var relationshipStatus = e.values[15];
    var insuranceGroupID = e.values[16];
    var suicideThoughts = e.values[21];
    var suicideComments = e.values[22];
    var currentSymptoms = e.values[24];
    var pastSymptoms = e.values[25];
    var relativesSymptoms = e.values[26];
    var referralSource = e.values[27];
    var emergencyContactName = e.values[28];
    var eduBackground = e.values[29];
    var emergencyContactNumber = e.values[30];
    var employment = e.values[31];
    var presentingConcern = e.values[32];
    var concernHistory = e.values[33];
    var symptomTrigger = e.values[34];
    var symptomSelfImpact = e.values[35];
    var symptomRelationshipImpact = e.values[36];
    var symptomCoping = e.values[37];
    var medConditions = e.values[38];
    var doctorCare = e.values[39];
    var medications = e.values[40];
    var fooChildhood = e.values[41];
    var fooCurrent = e.values[42];
    var socialInfo = e.values[43];
    var currentRels = e.values[44];
    var resources = e.values[45];
    var eduConcerns = e.values[46];
    var legalConcerns = e.values[47];
    var cultureConcerns = e.values[48];
    var religConcerns = e.values[49];
    var suicideUrges = e.values[50];
    var suicidePlans = e.values[51];
    var suicideAttempts = e.values[52];
    var insCarrier = e.values[53];
    var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById('1zsvcI6JwY_kdSCVs7w6gSh_VmwwtIe1E_Fm28b0GyvM');
    var templateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1j619jPkXGATxs99Uh6BbDu4e4lV0za_3');
    var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(lastName + ', ' + firstName, templateResponseFolder);
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
    var body = doc.getBody();
    var header = doc.getHeader();
    body.replaceText('{{lastName}}', lastName);
    body.replaceText('{{firstName}}', firstName);
    body.replaceText('{{email}}', email);
    body.replaceText('{{birthdate}}', birthdate);
    body.replaceText('{{timestamp}}', timestamp);
    body.replaceText('{{contactMethod}}', contactMethod);
    body.replaceText('{{contactSafetyCheck}}', safetyConcerns);
    body.replaceText('{{phoneNumber}}', phoneNumber);
    body.replaceText('{{textNumber}}', textNumber);
    body.replaceText('{{physAddress}}', physicalAddress);
    body.replaceText('{{mailAddress}}', mailingAddress);
    body.replaceText('{{emergContactName}}', emergencyContactName);
    body.replaceText('{{emergContactNumber}}', emergencyContactNumber);
    body.replaceText('{{referralSource}}', referralSource);
    body.replaceText('{{eduBackground}}', eduBackground);
    body.replaceText('{{employment}}', employment);
    body.replaceText('{{gender}}', gender);
    body.replaceText('{{pronouns}}', pronouns);
    body.replaceText('{{relStatus}}', relationshipStatus);
    body.replaceText('{{insCarrier}}', insCarrier);
    body.replaceText('{{insMemberID}}', insuranceMemberID);
    body.replaceText('{{insGroupID}}', insuranceGroupID);
    body.replaceText('{{presentingConcern}}', presentingConcern);
    body.replaceText('{{concernHistory}}', concernHistory);
    body.replaceText('{{currentSymptoms}}', currentSymptoms);
    body.replaceText('{{pastSymptoms}}', pastSymptoms);
    body.replaceText('{{famSymptoms}}', relativesSymptoms);
    body.replaceText('{{symptomTrigger}}', symptomTrigger);
    body.replaceText('{{symptomSelfImpact}}', symptomSelfImpact);
    body.replaceText('{{symptomRelImpact}}', symptomRelationshipImpact);
    body.replaceText('{{symptomCoping}}', symptomCoping);
    body.replaceText('{{medConditions}}', medConditions);
    body.replaceText('{{doctorCare}}', doctorCare);
    body.replaceText('{{medications}}', medications);
    body.replaceText('{{curentRels}}', currentRels);
    body.replaceText('{{fooChildhood}}', fooChildhood);
    body.replaceText('{{fooCurrent}}', fooCurrent);
    body.replaceText('{{socialInfo}}', socialInfo);
    body.replaceText('{{resources}}', resources);
    body.replaceText('{{eduConcerns}}', eduConcerns);
    body.replaceText('{{legalConcerns}}', legalConcerns);
    body.replaceText('{{cultureConcerns}}', cultureConcerns);
    body.replaceText('{{religConcerns}}', religConcerns);
    body.replaceText('{{suicideThoughts}}', suicideThoughts);
    body.replaceText('{{suicideComments}}', suicideComments);
    body.replaceText('{{suicideUrges}}', suicideUrges);
    body.replaceText('{{suicidePlans}}', suicidePlans);
    body.replaceText('{{suicideAttempts}}', suicideAttempts);
    header.replaceText('{{lastName}}', lastName);
    header.replaceText('{{firstName}}', firstName);
    doc.saveAndClose();
  }
  catch (error) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(error);
  }
}
```